# Centering and adding on hover and on click event to CSS3 button

Tags: html, css

I've just developed a CSS3 button via http://css3button.net/36045 and I was wondering how do I go about adding on hover and on click state changes (*i.e* defining the correct colours that go with the colour scheme). I don't know much about color codes and would appreciate any help.

Also, what would be the best way of centering the button in CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/snmSq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#element:hover { color: #fff; }
#element:active { color: #000; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What colours would you recommend that go with my current design?

Comment: @methuselah red for when you hover, a more yellowy green for active :) [see](http://jsfiddle.net/snmSq/2/)

Comment: I'd recommend you to fill the whole button with darker green color when hovered, or to switch the colors (light green -> down, dark green -> up).

Comment: @NikolaK. can you give me an CSS3 example: this is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/snmSq/1/

Comment: Usage of those events is absolutely same as without them. Just copy your default part (the WHOLE button.signup), add **:hover** and change what you want to be changed when hovered.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding :hover to class?  Eg:

```
 button.signup:hover {background:red;}
```

To center I would wrap the button in a div and then center it.

Comment: What about on button click? What should I use then?

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal centering use margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto, for vertical: margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto or simply float:center for all of them but be careful since floating always can create problems